# Extracting the value of $y$ from $x$ in an elliptic curve over a finite field

Tags: group-theory, elliptic-curves, finite-fields

Given an elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$ over a finite field $\mathbf{F}_p$, how can I retrieve the value of $y$ given the value of $x$?

My knowledge in this area is quite limited, so I understand this question might seems silly.

I'm currently working on an application that uses an elliptic curves library and I saw at some point that this value was retrieved via: 
$$(x^3 + ax + b)^{(p+1) >> 2} \mod p$$

the $>>$ means shift right though I am not sure what this means mathematically.

Does this make sense?

Thanks.

Comment: Right shift is equivalent to dividing by 2. So right-shifting twice is the same as dividing by $2^2=4$ : `24 >> 2 == 6` Now as to why $p$ can't be even...

Comment: Shift right is the same as division by 2.  The result follows by an application of Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: As for "why couldn't they be straightforward?": bit-twiddling is a cheaper operation than integer division, and it looks like the computing environment you are using does not optimize division operations when the divisor is a power of 2.

Comment: p can't be even because it is a large prime, but can I be certain that the (p+1) will divide by 4? Does the presented operation actually retrieve the value of y?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call $C = x^3+ax+b$.  You want to solve $y^2 = C$, which is a quadratic equation, specifically extracting a square root.  There are lots of ways to extract square roots.

For instance, the way you mention is the first method described in [this section of the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Prime_or_prime_power_modulus) on numbers that are squares (quadratic residues).  This only works if $p+1$ is divisible by $4$, but as a consequence of [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

It also links to a few efficient algorithms, including a [full algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanks-Tonelli_algorithm) that uses the one you mentioned if $p+1$ is divisible by $4$.